# Do curly braces inside json string objects need to be escaped?

Tags: json, escaping, curly-braces

This string is part a JSON object/file:

```
"Mask" : "{0}(CASE WHEN {1} = {2} THEN {3} ELSE 0 END) {4}"
```

Will JSON recognize that as part of standard JSON notation or do I need to escape those curly braces s somehow?

If so, how does one escape curly braces in JSON?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**No**. Curly braces do not have to be escaped in JSON.

Answer (score 17):

**No, curly braces do not have to be escaped in JSON strings.**

JSON is defined in [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159). The [Section 7: Strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7) lists the string characters that **must** be escaped:

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the
> quotation marks, except for the characters that **must** be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
> through U+001F).

While all characters can be escaped, curly braces do not have to be.